# Take numerous parts of string out of long string

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly long `String`

```
var str = "[FirmLegalEntity [firmLegalEntityCode=F2, name=Global Markets Limited, shortName=CMP, firmLeCodeShortName=null], FirmLegalEntity [firmLegalEntityCode=D7, name=BHG SINGAPORE LIMITED, shortName=CGL, firmLeCodeShortName=null]]"
```

I need all `firmLegalEntityCode`s.

I've tried using `Str.shift("=,")` but this gets nowhere near the desired output.

There is also the issue that other values in the string are surrounded by `=` and `,`.

Comment: a regular expression might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a regex:

```
var re = /firmLegalEntityCode=([^,]*),/g;
var s = '[FirmLegalEntity [firmLegalEntityCode=F2, name=Global Markets Limited, shortName=CMP, firmLeCodeShortName=null], FirmLegalEntity [firmLegalEntityCode=D7, name=BHG SINGAPORE LIMITED, shortName=CGL, firmLeCodeShortName=null]]';
var m;
while (m = re.exec(s)) {
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version

```js
var str = "[FirmLegalEntity [firmLegalEntityCode=F2, name=Global Markets Limited, shortName=CMP, firmLeCodeShortName=null], FirmLegalEntity [firmLegalEntityCode=D7, name=BHG SINGAPORE LIMITED, shortName=CGL, firmLeCodeShortName=null]]";

var leg = str.match(/firmLegalEntityCode\=.{2}/g).map(function(str) {
  return str.split("=")[1]
});
console.log(leg)
```